# ASP.NET Core - MVC - Model variable in view - null exception

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, nullreferenceexception

In an attempt to learn ASP.NET Core MVC I've made a simple project and am trying to pass a model instance created in the controller to the view.

**Controller Code** - *I create a simple list, then pass it to the view, being explicit about which view*

```
public class TableController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var modelData = new List<string> {"A", "B"};

            ViewBag.Title = "Tables";
            
            return View("/Pages/Table.cshtml", modelData);
        }
    }
```

**View Code**

```
@page
@model List<string>

    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">@ViewBag.Title</h1>

        @if (Model == null)
        {
            <p>There is no data to be displayed</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <ul>
                @foreach (string str in Model)
                {
                    <li>@str</li>
                }
            </ul>
        }
    </div>
```

When I set a breakpoint in the Controller the object I pass in as the model parameter is not null:
[image]

However, when I step through into the view code I get this:

[image]

I've looked at a few other "Model is null" posts but they were due **mismatching types** between whats passed in the View() model parameter and whats expected in the view given by the @model declaration.

It's probably something really simple but I'm not sure where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Maybe try with an actual custom class for the model where the List is a property of the model instead of being used directly. That's how MVC is supposed to work [Docs on adding a MVC model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?tabs=visual-studio#strongly-typed-models-and-the--keyword)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exception, the solution was to remove @page in Index.cshtml and then *Boom*, everything was there. Took me 5-6 hours to "resolve" this exception but better late, than never.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net MVC,View does not mean `Razor Page`.You can use a `View page`,And add a Table folder in Views.And then add a Index.cshtml(Razor View Page)to it.

Here is a demo worked:

Controller(`return View()` in`Index` action will find a Index.cshtml in Views/Table(Views/ControllerName)):

```
public class TableController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var modelData = new List<string> { "A", "B" };

            ViewBag.Title = "Tables";

            return View(modelData);
        }
    }
```

View(Don't use `@page`,it's used in Razor Page):

```
@model List<string>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Table_Index";
}
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">@ViewBag.Title</h1>

    @if (Model == null)
    {
        <p>There is no data to be displayed</p>
    }
    else
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach (string str in Model)
            {
                <li>@str</li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

Views folder structure(Each folder means a controller except `Shared`):

[image]

Result:
[image]